# SQL multiple table delete of posts using wildcard

Tags: sql, wordpress, wildcard, subdomain

Want to use the following SQL script to delete all old posts and related records from the entire DB with a single query.  The problem I'm having is that there are 112 subdomains (448 tables) within the DB (WordPress creates separate tables for every subdomain differentiated numerically) and I have been unable to correctly incorporate a table name wildcard.  As is, the script just deletes from each table one subdomain at a time.

```
delete a,b,c,d
FROM wp_112_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_112_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_112_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_112_term_taxonomy d ON ( d.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id )
AND a.post_type = 'post'
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), a.post_date) > 30
```

Comment: Any possibility you can redesign the db and use cascade delete?

Comment: I'm not familiar with cascade delete but if it requires a DB redesign I won't be able to use it.